# how to close the modal after action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am working on converting onclick javascript button to lightning button :
I am newly converting classic to lightning any help will be greatly appreciated

OLD CLASSIC Java SCRIPT CODE :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")} {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js")} 
var connection = sforce.connection; 
var qid="{!Quote__c.Id}"; 
var isedit="{!Quote__c.isEdited__c}"; 
var isPreviewed="{!Quote__c.isPreviewd__c}"; 
var isGenerated="{!Quote__c.Generated__c}"; 
var pot="{!Quote__c.potential__c}"; 
var x=pot.replace(/\,/g,''); 

var quot= new sforce.SObject("Quote__c"); 
quot.id=qid; 
if(isGenerated==true && isPreviewed==false){ 
alert('Please preview the quote then generate '); 
} 
else if(isedit==true && isPreviewed==false){ 
alert('Please preview the quote then generate '); 
}else{ 
parent.location.href = parent.location.href; 
window.open("/apex/QuotePDF?id={!Quote__c.Id}","_blank"); 
if(x>50000){ 
if (('{!$User.ProfileId}'=='00e90000000emPJ') || ('{!$User.ProfileId}'=='00e90000001k992' )){ 
alert('Please print the quote for manager signature'); 
}} 
}
```

Lightning component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

     <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.CheckPDF}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Quotepdf" type="Quote__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Quote__c'}" />

</aura:component>
```

Component controller :

```
({
    CheckPDF : function(component, event, helper) {

        // alert('Executing...' + component.get("v.recordId"));
         var qid=component.get("v.recordId"); 
         var isedit=component.get("v.isEdited__c"); 
         var isPreviewed=component.get("v.isPreviewd__c"); 
         var isGenerated=component.get("v.Generated__c"); 
         var pot=component.get("V.potential__c"); 
       //  var x=pot.replace(/\,/g,''); 
         if(isGenerated==true && isPreviewed==false){ 
         alert('Please preview the quote then generate '); 
         } 
         else if(isedit==true && isPreviewed==false){ 
         alert('Please preview the quote then generate '); 
         }else{ 
         parent.location.href = parent.location.href; 
         window.open("/apex/QuotePDF?id=qid","_blank"); 
         if(pot>50000){ 
         if (('{!$User.ProfileId}'=='00e90000000emPJ') || ('{!$User.ProfileId}'=='00e90000001k992' )){ 
         alert('Please print the quote for manager signature'); 
             }          
         }  
       }
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();

    }    
})
```

[image]

> I tried to close the modal after button click but this is not  getting
>   closed

Any help will be greatly appreciated :

Comment: There are many issues in this code snippet you shared, look like you have mixed the VF and lightning syntax here... `if (('{!$User.ProfileId}'=='00e90000000emPJ')`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 still i didn't pass that logic .I am still working on first alert message

Comment: it looks like a quick action - Salesforce is making the modal and the closing functionality of the modal. please tell how do you implement the modal and what do you do to close it

Comment: @ItaiShmida var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire(); i tried this action whis is not closing

Comment: how do you open the modal / create the button?

Comment: @ItaiShmida force:lightningQuickAction i am creating a custom button on object page

Comment: and a click on the X button does not close the modal?